# Scrape web with x-ray

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, x-ray

I'm using x-ray to extract some data from a web site but when I get to the point to crawl to another page using the built-in functionality, it simply doesn't work.

**UnitPrice** is the parameter I want to extract but I get "*undefined*" all the time.

As you can see, I'm passing the href value previously extracted on the url property.

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray();
var x = Xray({
  filters: {
    cleanPrice: function (value) {
      return typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/\r|\t|\n|€/g, "").trim() : value
    },
    whiteSpaces: function (value) {
      return typeof value === 'string' ? value.replace(/ +/g, ' ').trim() : value
    }
  }
});

x('https://www.simply.es/compra-online/aceite-vinagre-y-sal.html',
  '#content > ul',
  [{
    name: '.descripcionProducto | whiteSpaces',
    categoryId: 'input[name="idCategoria"]@value',
    productId: 'input[name="idProducto"]@value',
    url: 'li a@href',
    price: 'span | cleanPrice',
    image: '.miniaturaProducto@src',
    unitPrice: x('li a@href', '.precioKilo')
  }])
  .paginate('.link@href')
  .limit(1)
  // .delay(500, 1000)
  // .throttle(2, 1000)
  .write('results.json')
```

Comment: I cant understand why this library got so many stars, if there is almost no tutorials on the web and the docs are really poor.

Comment: I think the docs are not up-to-date but the library still has potential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pull request to fix this. Meanwhile you can use the solution which is just one line of code. See this:

https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray/pull/181